# Failing to mount SCSI from HP Modular Smart Array (MSA20)

Tags: filesystems, mount, scsi, inode, hp-modular-smart-array

I have acquired a HP dl360 g4p with a MSA20 Modular Smart Array.

Currently I have Arch Linux installed on it since I had some issues with the graphics. But that is not why I am asking a question.

There is an issue with mounting the array. I currently have two logical drives consisting of 500GB harddrives in RAID 6.

In Linux the two logical drives is showing up as two seperate devices (/dev/cciss/c0d0 and /dev/cciss/c0d1) with sizes of 1800 something GB).
No issues with partitioning the two devices into /dev/cciss/c0d0p1 and /dev/cciss/c0d1p1.

But where it all goes wrong is when mounting the partitions. Error messages follows as:

```
random_server_name% sudo mount /dev/cciss/c0d1p1 /mnt/disk1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/cciss/c0d1p1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

And the output from `dmesg | tail` is:

```
random_server_name% dmesg | tail
[ 5522.310178] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985000 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.330529] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985780 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.350805] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985500 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.371078] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985a00 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.391385] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985c80 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.411697] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985280 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.432025] cciss 0000:0b:04.0: cmd ffff880037985000 has CHECK CONDITION sense key = 0x5
[ 5522.489858] VFS: Dirty inode writeback failed for block device cciss/c0d1p1 (err=-5).
[ 5524.703565] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[ 5524.703574] EXT4-fs (cciss!c0d1p1): error loading journal
```

I have tried to fix the filesystem using `fsck` but it did not work.
Also there is no connectivity issues since it was possible to communicate using `hpacucli` which enables you to show information about the storage array and enables you to configure it.

Cheers

Comment: Have your tried mounting a scsi LUN from another operating system and formatting or just from ARCH?

Answer (score 1):

I'm hoping you created filesystems after you defined the partitions. I'm assuming ext4?

Anyway, the cciss `CHECK CONDITION` errors in dmesg indicate an array failure.

I know this is Arch, so HP support is pretty poor, but can you see if you can install `hpssacli` or `hpacucli`?

---

I'd like to see the output of:

`hpacucli ctrl all show config` and `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail`

Comment: I've already installed `hpacucli` and there is no issue with communicating with the array.

Comment: Please provide the output of `hpacucli ctrl all show config` and `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail` in your question.

Comment: [Output from the commands](http://pastebin.com/EPFrG4iQ)

Comment: How did you create the filesystem? Show the command. Please show the output of "fdisk -l" and "blkid"

Comment: I used `parted /dev/cciss/c0d0` and then `mklabel gpt`, `mkpart primary ext4 1MiB 100%`, after that I ran the command `mkfs.ext4 /dev/cciss/c0d0p1`.
Here is the output from the commands [`fdisk -l`](http://pastebin.com/Gj0gPjbb) and [`blkid`](http://pastebin.com/y824tyzG)